# Know the count of lines that are connected to each point

Tags: qgis, python

I have a lot of points. Each one is connected to one or more lines. The lines have also more than one direction (max 4 directions). So how to figure out a method to identify the count of lines for each direction?

For example :
I have a point layer that has one point (let's assume point_No. 1 ) this point is surrounded by 3 direction like direction 1 have 4 lines, direction 2 has 8 lines, and direction 3 have 12 line so the output of the code should be

Point No. | Direction 1 | Direction 2 | Direction 3 | Direction 4
output will be : 1 | 4 | 8 | 12

This is what I have [image]

What i tried is :
1- Explode lines on the lines layer
[image]

2- apply expression on the Exploded lines layer
[image]

3- this is the result after applying the expression
[image]

4- when I tried to Delete duplicate geometries for the Exploded Layer
there was an error Feature (544) from “Exploded” has invalid geometry. Please fix the geometry or change the “Invalid features filtering” option for this input or globally in Processing settings.
Execution failed after 0.05 seconds but I fixed it by using fix geometries and then re-applying the expression so I got new line layer which is Cleaned
[image]

4- then I Extract vertices on the original line layer so I get a new point layer which is Vertices
[image]

5- Then I Delete duplicate geometries on the Vertices layer and a new layer is created which is Cleaned_Vertices
[image]

6- The last step was running the expression using a field calculator and creating a new field called counts with the following expression
array_to_string(
overlay_touches(
'Cleaned_Vertices',"count"
)
)
[image]

and this is what I got
[image]

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. You need the count of overlapping lines that touch the respective point for each direction sparately? Are these exact line overlaps?

Comment: @winnewoerp Yes they overlapped the screenshot shows there are 8 or 12 or 4 which means there is 8 line or 12 lines...etc in the same path

Comment: Ok, if it's even the same paths it may even possible to skip the Explode step of my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using Python/PyQGIS, you could use different processing tools (or even create a graphical model), including some geometry expressions. If you have exactly overlapping lines (sharing the same vertices along the overlapping section) you could do the following:

1. Use **Explode lines** processing tool on your original line layer
2. Add an integer field `count` to each exploded line using the **Field calculator** algorithm with the following expression (replace `'exploded_line_layer'` with the correct layer name):

```
array_length(
  overlay_equals(
    'exploded_line_layer',$id
  )
) + 1
```

3. **Delete duplicate geometries** using the result from the previous step
4. **Extract vertices** of your original layer
5. **Delete duplicate geometries** of your new point layer
6. Add a new integer field `counts` to your cleaned point layer using the **Field calculator** processing tool using the following expression (replace `'cleaned_line_layer'` with the correct layer name from the result of step 3):

```
array_to_string(
  overlay_touches(
    'cleaned_line_layer',"count"
  )
)
```

The result with labels of `count` and `counts` fields then looks like this:

[image: Result]

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: I currently have two issues. The first, and most significant, problem is that some lines do not end with a point. Consequently, I am unsure of the method to ensure that all lines are split when they reach a point and do not cross through it. The second issue pertains to the last point. When attempting to add a new integer field 'counts' to my cleaned point layer using the Field Calculator processing tool with the following expression 
array_to_string(overlay_touches('cleaned_point_layer', 'count'))
I observed that all the values in the 'counts' field are NULL.

Comment: Can you provide example data or edit the question to give more details? It's hard to tell what's going wrong without having more information on your actual data. Maybe also add to the question what you have tried so far based on my answer including screenshots.

Comment: Let me clarify further.

I have multiple points, and each of these points is connected by more than one line. As illustrated in the image in the question, this point is connected by 8 vectors on one side, 4 vectors on another side, and 12 vectors on yet another side. Therefore, I want to calculate the number of lines on each side, as explained in your response, but what you provided did not work for me

Comment: I have edited the question and implemented all the solutions you provided. You can view the result now.

Comment: There was an error in step 6 of my answer. I corrected it. You have to use your result from step 3 in the expression where it now says `cleaned_line_layer`. Hope that it works now.

Comment: Worked !! Many Thanks for you